# how to echo out associative part of associative array bash

Tags: bash

Here is an example of an associative array:

```
declare -A contains=( 
['sass']=exist")
```

I wish to check if 'sass' is present in a variable. So my next line is:

```
if [[ '????' = 'sass' ]]
  etc
  etc
```

However, i not sure what to put in the if statement to check the first part of the associative array.

Any help is appreciated, 
Thanks!

Comment: `if [[ ${contains[sass]} ]]`; there's no `=` involved anywhere.

Comment: ...keep in mind that an associative array can have any number of keys, so you can't just retrieve "the key part" and operate on it; the nearest you could do is to iterate over the list of *all* the keys, but that's very inefficient compared to just asking for a lookup of the specific one you're looking for.